# Sonar 4.3 and C# 3.1 not executing testcases

Tags: sonarqube, gallio

Just upgraded to Sonar 4.3 and C# 3.1 and now my tests are not being run/don't show up in Sonar. What do I need to change to get this work in this upgraded environment? Tried to run with sonar.visualstudio.enable=true to minimize configuration in sonar-project.properties.

Everything has been running before the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Since C# 3.0, the automatic execution of tests via Gallio has been dropped, as you can see in the [SONARCS-37](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARCS-37) ticket.

This means you must run the tests and generate reports before launching the SonarQUbe analysis, and use the reuse report capabilities of the plugin to import those test results in SonarQube.

Comment: I have generated reports and specefied the path in sonar-project.properties but Sonar doesn't seem to pick them up. What could be wrong?  

sonar.gallio.mode=reuseReport
sonar.gallio.reports.path=UnitTestResults.xml

The UnitTestResults.xml file is located in the base directory, same as the .sln file

Comment: Gallio is no more supported in the latest versions, so those properties are out-dated. Please read the documentation to get the correct properties.

Comment: Ok, as I understand it I am supposed to use: <ProjectName>.sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=<nameofreport>.trx What if I dont know the project name in the config? It is used for many projects. Also my testresults report is in .xml format will that work?